GitLab | Determine version of sidekiq
I am struggling to determine the version of sidkiq GitLab Omnibus uses within its corresponding installation.
Preferrably, I could derive that information from the source code, to be able to see which version is being used now and in future versions to come.
As always, any help is higly appreciated.
